# can unnormalized load centrality be non-integer?

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to use the python NetworkX package to validate some other code, but I am worried that load centrality does not mean what I think.  When I run the example below, I expect to only get integer values for load since it should just be a count at each node of the number of shortest paths passing through the node (i.e., I list out all the shortest paths between node pairs, then for each node 'v' count how many paths cross it, excluding paths where 'v' is the first or last node):

```
edges = [ ('a0','a1'),('a0','a2'),('a1','a4'),('a1','a2'),('a2','a4'),('a2','z5'),('a2','a3'),('a3','z5'),('a4','z5'),('a4','z6'),('a4','z7')
     ,('z5','z6'),('z5','z7'),('z5','z8'),('z6','z7'),('z6','z8'),('z6','z9'),('z7','z8'),('z7','z9'),('z8','z9')]
import networkx as nx
testg = nx.Graph( edges )
nx.load_centrality( testg, normalized=False )
```

I get output like this:

```
{'a0': 0.0,
 'a1': 3.16666665,
 'a2': 15.4999998,
 'a3': 0.0,
 'a4': 14.75,
 'z5': 20.25,
 'z6': 6.04166666,
 'z7': 6.04166666,
 'z8': 2.24999996,
 'z9': 0,0}
```

These are similar to the values I compute by hand in terms of relative size, but why aren't they integer values?  Every other network that I have tested returns integer values for unnormalized load centrality, and I don't see anything in the definition that would lead to these values.  The python doc for this function says to see betweenness and also provides an article as reference for the algorithm (which I can't access).

Comment: As for the python doc reference this may be the same article, https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e3f3/35cf508f501b0e9c382ae3c445b29f34a58d.pdf

Comment: What do you expect the algorithm to do if a pair of nodes has two different shortest paths?

Comment: Consider four nodes connected in a square; each node is included in one shortest path between opposite corners, but unnormalized load is reported as 1 from networkx.load_centrality.

Comment: downshift, I think that is the right article, thanks!  But they only define betweenness in that paper.  I'm wondering if 'load' is some transform of that betweenness value?

Answer (score 1):

After very extensive calculations based on the paper Downshift linked to, it looks like 'load' follows the betweenness definition in that paper but subtracts off a factor of (2n-1) to adjust for some overcounting in the algorithm.  Either that, or the algorithm in the paper doesn't make clear that the initial packets of size '1' should only contribute to nodes they pass through and not to the ends of the paths.  In any case, I can match the output values of networkx now.  The values differ from networkx's own betweenness function which follows the formula in the documentation based on node pairs rather than propagating packets of size 1 through the network.

In particular, because the packets split into equal size at branch points, nodes can accumulate partial packets and therefore accumulate a non-integer 'load' value.  That's not what the description implies in the networkx documentation, but it's clear enough now.